# Is priority important in `Series` expansion?

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

I have a strange case here! The story begins with this equation

```
t22b=(r - rh)*(-2*rh*\[Kappa]g - (24*G^2*\[Eta]*\[Kappa]g^2)/rh^2 + 
  (Q^2*(3 - 8*b^2*G*Sqrt[Pi]*(-3*Sqrt[Pi] + 
        Sqrt[4*Pi + Q^2/(b^2*rh^4)])*rh^2 - 
      4*b*G*Sqrt[Pi]*Sqrt[Q^2 + 4*b^2*Pi*rh^4] - 3*rh^2*\[CapitalLambda]) + 
    12*b^2*Pi*rh^4*(1 + 8*b^2*G*Pi*rh^2 - 
      4*b*G*Sqrt[Pi]*Sqrt[Q^2 + 4*b^2*Pi*rh^4] - rh^2*\[CapitalLambda]))/
   (3*(Q^2 + 4*b^2*Pi*rh^4)))
```

Firstly, one can expand `t22b` as follows

```
(Series[t22b, {b, Infinity, 0}] // Normal // PowerExpand // 
    FullSimplify // Expand) // FullSimplify
```

The result will be

```
-(((r - rh) (G (Q^2 + 24 G \[Eta] \[Kappa]g^2) + 
    rh^2 (-1 + 2 rh \[Kappa]g + rh^2 \[CapitalLambda])))/rh^2)
```

Now, solving above term equal to zero for `\[Kappa]g` we have (note that, this answer is true for my problem)

```
\[Kappa]g -> (-2 rh^3 + Sqrt[
  4 rh^6 - 96 G^2 \[Eta] (G Q^2 - rh^2 + rh^4 \[CapitalLambda])])/(
 48 G^2 \[Eta]).
```

In the second method, one can find `\[Kappa]g` from the `eq22b=0` and then expand the answer.

```
sol1 = Solve[(t22b) == 0, \[Kappa]g] // PowerExpand // FullSimplify
```

```
\[Kappa]a = \[Kappa]g /. sol1[[1]];
\[Kappa]b = \[Kappa]g /. sol1[[2]];
```

The expanded result is

```
Series[\[Kappa]a, {b, Infinity, 0}] // PowerExpand // FullSimplify
Series[\[Kappa]b, {b, Infinity, 0}] // PowerExpand // FullSimplify
```

Non of these expanded answers reproduce the `\[Kappa]g` of previous procedure.
Why?! wHy?! WhY?!!!
It is driving me crazy :))
Can you help?

Comment: I do not understand why do you need all these `PowerExpand` and `FullSimplify`. `Assuming[b > 0 && rh > 0, Series[t22b, {b, Infinity, 0}]]`does the job. Notice extra term.

Comment: @yarchik : yes it is true. However, doesn't matter so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get identical answers. Let `sA` be the result of the series expansion and solution, and let `sB` be the result of solution followed by the series expansions. There are 2 roots. They are identical modulo permutation.

```
sA=Assuming[b>0&&rh>0,κg/.Solve[(Series[t22b,{b,Infinity,0}]//Normal)==0,κg]];
sB=Assuming[b>0&&rh>0,Series[κg/.Solve[t22b==0,κg],{b,Infinity,0}]//Normal];
FullSimplify[sA[[1]]-sB[[2]]]
FullSimplify[sA[[2]]-sB[[1]]]
Out[1]= 0
Out[2]= 0
```

Comment: Thanks. The problems are missing the `Normal` command and also conditions on `rh` and `b`. Now it is true :)